# Why is there a triangle missing from the return value of d3.voronoi.triangles?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mesh, voronoi

Discovered this while using triangles() to generate a mesh for interpolating some points. Noticed that some of my points were not inside any triangles. I was surprised to find that a triangle was missing from the mesh. Pruned my data down to 4 vertices, which should yield 2 triangles, but yields just 1. I've tried tweaking the vertices slightly, which results in the expect number of triangles.

```
v = require("d3-voronoi").voronoi();

vertices = [[47.307,105.33],[51.707,104.13],[52.717,110.74],[53.917,106.34]];

console.log(v.triangles(vertices)); // returns 1 triangle

vertices[3][1] += 0.001 // tweak one of the values slightly

console.log(v.triangles(vertices)); // returns 2 triangles (as expected)
```

https://tonicdev.com/56f99ca738ca281100ea16ad/573f3672a04fd4110009ee44

I have not had much luck stepping though d3-voronoi (comparing the path of the failure to the successful case) since I'm not familiar with the algorithm used.

I suspect numerical error, but I'm not sure how to track down or workaround this issue.

Looking for help resolving the issue in d3-voronoi (ideally), or a recommendation for another (numerically stable) mesh generating function.

Comment: I've worked around this bug by switching to another package: [delaunay-triangulate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/delaunay-triangulate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I circled back to this question eventually and posted a [issue](https://github.com/d3/d3-voronoi/issues/22) to the d3-voronoi repo.

The answer came back quickly, *cocircular points*, which (put simply) are a problem for the voronoi algorithm.

My options are to add some random jitter to my data or compute the triangles directly. As stated earlier, I've opted for the latter using the [delaunay-triangulate](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=delaunay-triangulate) package